# prevent swing dialog self dismissed by click/toch outside

Tags: swing, gradle

i have followind definition in gradle for asking a pass:

```
def askPass() {
    def msg = 'Please enter the passphrase for the keyfile:'
    def console = System.console()
    return console != null
          ? console.readPassword('%s: ', msg)
          : javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(msg)
}
```

i use it to gather pass  at when some task nearly ends - task is run (gradle myTask) from IDE (intellij)  in terminal - so it is a separate not tied to idee process, normally the dialog opens and i can write my pas but sometimes when the task takes long time im moving out IDE to do some other things moving a focus from IDE and when the task is at the end it invokes def to ask pass and gains focus popping up dialog on top of everything (im on linux os)

now to the point:

when i do something and the dialogs popups sometimes i don't react so fast or my hands are fasters as my eyes  as i was ocuppied by then other job - i click outside dialog area and the poped up dialog dissapears - no buttons are hitted... now the popup is gone the task is not done waiting for input ... (this looks like dismiss dialog by click outside and the dismiss result is not handled) in this def

so my question:

how can i make the popup no dismissable till the cancel or ok buttion is not used  (by click/select/accept) ?

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: please add language tag

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [modal dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window). It forces the user to select a choice before leaving to previous window. In your case, you should use [javax.swing.JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead of javax.swing.JOptionPane.

Comment: [All dialogs are modal. Each showXxxDialog method blocks the caller until the user's interaction is complete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)